# Encoding a string to show up correctly in the Browser

Tags: c#, http, url, character-encoding, urlencode

How would I change a url from % to %25 for a URL? I know I could use `.Replace("%", "%25")`, but what my real goal would be is to make all the conversions found [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) take place. Is there a built in function to do this or will I need to do a loop for ALL of the encoding here? I thought I was onto something with this code:

`string link = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode("https://www.somegenericsite.com?something=%");`

... but it returned the exact same link, not the encoded one. Any help or a nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://www.somegenericsite.com?something=%")
```

This will result in

```
https%3a%2f%2fwww.somegenericsite.com%3fsomething%3d%25
```

Comment: Actually messed my application up at first, but looks like only the last part of concatenation needs to be encoded... Don't ask why they wrote it like that, I'm just a lowly integrator! >.<